# Orientdb network connection lost during commit

Tags: orientdb

I am using the blueprints graph api for orient against a 2 node cluster running orient `1.7.10`. When ingesting simple parent child data I  intermittently get the following error on commit -

> Warning: caught I/O errors from not connected (local socket=?), trying to reconnect (error: java.io.IOException: Channel is closed)

The connection is then reestablished:

> Connection re-acquired transparently after 31ms and 1 retries: no errors will be thrown at application level.

This occurs mid way through the commit (100 vertices and edges) with the result that the server thinks it has sent the response but the client hangs forever.

Is there a way to catch this at the application level and e.g. rollback?

I would be very grateful for any help?

Comment: I suggest you to use OrientDB 2.0-SNAPSHOT from https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/orientechnologies/orientdb-community/2.0-SNAPSHOT/

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I currently cannot move to a snapshot as am looking to deploy to a production  environment. I have tried with 2.0 M3 and M2 but encountered other problems. Is there anything I can do on 1.7.10? Eg set a time out on the commit or cause the server to expect an ACK on successful receipt of the response?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know a very similar issue was fixed some time ago: https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/2930

one thing to be aware is that autostart transaction of the graph, if is enabled (and it is by default) you don't need to do begin, but just commit, if you do begin the transaction will be committed at shutdown and in that case can create that problem.

another suggestion is migrate to 2.0-* releases that have important improvement also in that side, especially if you are in development phase, the 2.0 final is going to be released very soon and will be the one with major focus in the next months.

bye

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. The issue looks to be related but the code does not do a begin as this is automatic as you say. It does do multiple commits and it is during these commits that the connection drop is experienced and not at shutdown. I really want to get this working with 1.7 as waiting for 2.0 will delay deployment.